# How to Access enum value in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom dictionary with key as an enum and values as custom object. i need to bind this object in the xaml. so how i can do it?

what i want to do is,

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[my enum value].Text}"></Button>
```

what i have tried,

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[local:MyEnum.Report].Text}"></Button>

<Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[x:Static local:MyEnum.Report].Text}">
</Button>

<Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[{x:Static local:MyEnum.Report}].Text}">
</Button>
```

But any of the above is not worked for me.and following code is displaying the enum value,

```
<Button Content="{x:Static local:MyEnum.Report}"></Button>
```

Enum file,

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Home,
    Report
}
```

my dictionary,

```
IDictionary<MyEnum, Button> ButtonGroups
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only have to use the `Enum` value, But `Button` does not have a `Text` property, so I used `Content`

```
 <Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[Home].Content}">
```

Test Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" x:Name="UI" Width="294" Height="79" >

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
         <Button Content="{Binding ButtonGroups[Home].Content}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ButtonGroups.Add(MyEnum.Home, new Button { Content = "Hello" });
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonGroups");
    }

    private Dictionary<MyEnum, Button> _buttonGroups = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Button>();
    public Dictionary<MyEnum, Button> ButtonGroups
    {
        get { return _buttonGroups; }
        set { _buttonGroups = value; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Home,
        Report
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I got it working by `<Button Content="{Binding Path=ButtonGroups[(local:MyEnum)Home].Text}"/>`, but seems this is much easier :) and `Text` is not a property of button. that collection contains custom objects and that custom object has a property called `Text`. thanks for the quick reply and working answer

Comment: No problems :) Happy coding